# How do I set a specific table in kafka sink connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using confluent kafka connector.
I want to insert data into a specific table, TB_TEST_KAFKA, in the sink connector.
I have already created the table.

auto.create=false.

I don't know a properties table name key ​​of the sink connector.
I'm trying to insert into specific table, TB_TEST_KAFKA,

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
errors.log.include.messages=true
dialect.name=SqlServerDatabaseDialect
connection.password=####
tasks.max=1
topics=test-topic
auto.evolve=false
connection.user=kafkauser
auto.create=false
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://####:1433;databaseName=TEST
errors.log.enable=true
insert.mode=insert
db.name=TB_TEST_KAFKA
```

But error

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Table "TB_TEST_KAFKA" is missing and auto-creation is disabled
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.create(DbStructure.java:116)
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.createOrAmendIfNecessary(DbStructure.java:68)
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:123)
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:73)
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:75)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:586)
... 10 more
```

Is there any way to put it into the table??

Answer (score 2):

JDBC Sink connector use the topic name as the basis for the naming of the table that it populates. You can use the [`RegExRouter`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html) to customize the name of the table (add these lines to your connector properties):

```
transforms=renameTopic
transforms.renameTopic.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
transforms.renameTopic.regex=test-topic
transforms.renameTopic.replacement=TB_TEST_KAFKA
```

Comment: If it(TB_TEST_KAFKA) is synonyms, do I need to set another setting??

Comment: Do you mean if topic name is `TB_TEST_KAFKA`?

Comment: If you don't need an actual regex pattern, `InsertField` transform would be more performant

Comment: In addition of what @OneCricketeer said, you can find more infoation in [Confluent documentation about SMTs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/overview.html)

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander I mean sysnonyms is database terminology (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander The kafka data was put into that table(TB_TEST_KAFKA) in the way you told me.  However, in the case of synonyms in sql server, the same error occurs.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the transform should maybe be called `renameTable`...  Otherwise, the same properties can be used with any source connector to rename the topic

Answer (score 0):

You can implement TableNamingStrategy and override resolveTableName() method.

table.naming.strategy

io.debezium.connector.jdbc.naming.DefaultTableNamingStrategy

Specifies the fully-qualified class name of a TableNamingStrategy implementation that the connector uses to resolve table names from incoming event topic names.

The default behavior is to:

```
Replace the ${topic} placeholder in the table.name.format configuration property with the event’s topic.

Sanitize the table name by replacing dots (.) with underscores (_).
```

Comment: how do you change/ override the tablenaming strategy? do you change the code and recompile it or we can upload something somewhere and define it in the config?